# Azure Pipelines coalesce not being evaluated

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've got template where I want to evaluate `coalesce(${{ parameters.pipeline }}, $(System.DefinitionId))`.

As far as I know, this is the proper syntax:

```yaml
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    inputs:
      buildType: 'specific'
      project: '$(System.TeamProjectId)'
      pipeline: $[ coalesce(${{ parameters.pipeline }}, $(System.DefinitionId)) ]
      buildVersionToDownload: latestFromBranch
      branchName: $[ coalesce(${{ parameters.branchName }}, $(Build.SourceBranch)) ]
      allowPartiallySucceededBuilds: true
      downloadType: 'single'
      downloadPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      artifactName: ${{ parameters.artifact }}
```

However, when I run this, I get this error:

> Definition name $[ coalesce(141, 342) ] didn't correspond to a valid definition

I *think* this likely means that it's not evaluating the expression and using the literal string `'$[ coalesce(141, 342) ]'`.

It seems that `Build.DefinitionId` is only available at runtime, else I'd set the parameter default to `${{ Build.DefinitionId }}`, and just set `pipeline: ${{ parameters.pipeline }}`.

I've tried a dozen different variants using `$[ ]`, `${{ }}`, and `$( )` syntaxes both inside and outside the `coalesce()`.  None of them work, but this one is the closest since it actually substitutes the variables in correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to place the expression in the job's `variables`, as well as use `variables['System.DefinitionId']` instead of the `$( )` syntax.

```yaml
- job: #...
  variables:
    pipeline: $[ coalesce(${{ parameters.pipeline }}, variables['System.DefinitionId']) ]
    branchName: $[ coalesce(${{ parameters.branchName }}, variables['Build.SourceBranch']) ]
  steps:
  # ...
  - task: DownlaodBuildArtifact@0
    inputs:
      # ...
      pipeline: $(pipeline)
      branchName: $(branchName)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) once you can, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: I needed to do the same thing, beware if parameters.pipeline is ever null, that expression will fail unless you wrap it in quotes like so:
'${{ parameters.pipeline }}'

Comment: Why did you have to put it in a variable and not just the input directly?

Comment: @ZachLeighton it's been a while, but iirc, coalesce doesn't work in `inputs`.  Don't quote me on that.  Also, this stuff is complicated, and I'm a newb at it.

Comment: Reference a similar question!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76667257/853030