# use functions with macro syntax variables yaml pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

How do I use [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions), like `upper()` together with [macro syntax variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax) like $(variable)?

I'd like to use a runtime-variable in a step-name and would like to use a function to make it uppercase. With template expression variables `${{ variables.var }}`, this is quite easy. `${{ upper(variables.var) }}`.
But if I try `upper($var)` I just get **upper(varcontent)**.

Thanks for helping me out on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Pipelines coalesce not being evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63729875/azure-pipelines-coalesce-not-being-evaluated)