# Azure Pipeline steplist template: Referencing a parameter in another parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am attempting to create an Azure Pipelines template that contains a list of steps. It contains a `steps` object and some `parameters`. The idea is that I can reference this template in another file's `steps` object, along with other templates, such that the list will flatten into a single steplist with steps from various templates. This is what I currently have:

```yaml
parameters:
# The solution configuration to be used, e.g. Release, Debug, etc.
- name: solutionConfig
  type: string
  default: Release

steps:
# Build the target
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build the target
  inputs:
    configuration: ${{ parameters.solutionConfig }}
```

This works fine and I am able to use the step as a template in another file. The issue I am facing is trying to create another parameter that uses the value of `solutionConfig`, but is over-writable by the user of the template. Something like this:

```yaml
parameters:
# The solution configuration to be used, e.g. Release, Debug, etc.
- name: solutionConfig
  type: string
  default: Release
# The path where binaries are created after compiling.
- name: binContentWildcard
  type: string
  default: '**/${{ parameters.solutionConfig }}/**/*.msi'

steps:
# Build the target
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build the target
  inputs:
    configuration: ${{ parameters.solutionConfig }}
# Copy binaries to staging directory
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: Copy binary artifacts
  inputs:
    contents: ${{ parameters.binContentWildcard }}
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/bin
```

However, this results in a `A template expression is not allowed in this context` error in Azure Pipelines (referring to the default value supplied to `binContentWildcard`) and the pipeline is not able to run.

In the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script), they indicate:

> Parameters are only available at template parsing time. Parameters are expanded just before the pipeline runs so that values surrounded by ${{ }} are replaced with parameter values. Use variables if you need your values to be more widely available during your pipeline run.

I tried using a variable to provide runtime resolution, like the following:

```yaml
parameters:
# The solution configuration to be used, e.g. Release, Debug, etc.
- name: solutionConfig
  type: string
  default: Release
# The path where binaries are created after compiling.
- name: binContentWildcard
  type: string
  default: ''

variables:
  ${{ if eq(parameters.binContentWildcard, '') }}:
    binContentWildcardVar: '**/${{ parameters.solutionConfig }}/**/*.msi'
  ${{ if ne(parameters.binContentWildcard, '') }}:
    binContentWildcardVar: ${{ parameters.binContentWildcard }}

steps:
# Build the target
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build the target
  inputs:
    configuration: ${{ parameters.solutionConfig }}
# Copy binaries to staging directory
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: Copy binary artifacts
  inputs:
    contents: $(binContentWildcardVar)
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/bin
```

But this results in a `Unexpected value` error in Azure Pipelines with regards to defining variables in this scope. This is because the template is referenced from the context of a `step`, but variables can only be declared in the context of a `pipeline`, `stage`, or `job`.

I don't think this is supported, but I also tried to use the runtime expression syntax with the `binContentWildcard` parameter:

```yaml
parameters:
# The solution configuration to be used, e.g. Release, Debug, etc.
- name: solutionConfig
  type: string
  default: Release
# The path where binaries are created after compiling.
- name: binContentWildcard
  type: string
  default: '**/$[ parameters.solutionConfig ]/**/*.msi'

steps:
# Build the target
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build the target
  inputs:
    configuration: ${{ parameters.solutionConfig }}
# Copy binaries to staging directory
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: Copy binary artifacts
  inputs:
    contents: $[ parameters.binContentWildcard ]
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/bin
```

However, this results in the string literal `"$[ parameters.binContentWildcard ]"` being supplied to the `contents` input.

Is it possible to use the value of a parameter in another parameter within the context of a steplist template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution suggested by DreadedFrost may work for some. However, having a template at the scope of a `steplist` is really what I wanted in my situation.

My solution is similar to my original attempt and DreadedFrost's answer, expect that the variables are created by the `task.setvariable` logging command, which allows the variables to be dynamically created by a step and be referenced by subsequent steps in the same job without needing a `variables` element in the template.

```yaml
parameters:
# The solution configuration to be used, e.g. Release, Debug, etc.
- name: solutionConfig
  type: string
  default: Release
# The path where binaries are created after compiling.
- name: binContentWildcard
  type: string
  default: ''

steps:
# Create dynamic variables that depend on parameter inputs
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=binContentWildcardVar]${{ coalesce(parameters.binContentWildcard, format('**/{0}/**/*.msi', parameters.solutionConfig)) }}"
# Build the target
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build the target
  inputs:
    configuration: ${{ parameters.solutionConfig }}
# Copy binaries to staging directory
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: Copy binary artifacts
  inputs:
    contents: $(binContentWildcardVar)
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this situation the tasks should form a job template. To best scale templates it is usually recommend to have a task template, a job template calling task templates, and a stage calling stage templates.

In this situation I would recommend something like the following:

```
parameters:
# The solution configuration to be used, e.g. Release, Debug, etc.
- name: solutionConfig
  type: string
  default: Release
# The path where binaries are created after compiling.
- name: binContentWildcard
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: serviceName
  type: string
  default: ''

jobs:
- job: '{{ parameters.serviceName }}_job'
  variables:
  ${{ if eq(parameters.binContentWildcard, '') }}:
    binContentWildcardVar: '**/${{ parameters.solutionConfig }}/**/*.msi'
  ${{ if ne(parameters.binContentWildcard, '') }}:
    binContentWildcardVar: ${{ parameters.binContentWildcard }}

  steps:
      # Build the target
  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: Build the target
    inputs:
      configuration: ${{ parameters.solutionConfig }}
  # Copy binaries to staging directory
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Copy binary artifacts
    inputs:
      contents: $(binContentWildcardVar)
      targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/bin
```

The `serviceName` has been included to denote that a job of the same name can only appear once per stage so making this flexible will help at scale.

This job template would be called in a stage via:

```
  jobs:
    - template: job_template.yml
```

Comment: Thanks, the tip about the typical template organization paradigm is helpful. I'll try to reorganize my templates with this structure.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
parameters:
- name: csProjectName
  type: string
- name: requiredProjects
  type: string
  default: ''  

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: ${{ coalesce(parameters.requiredProjects, format('src/{0}/*.csproj', parameters.csProjectName)) }}
    verbosityRestore: Minimal
    workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: nuget.config
  displayName: "nuget restore"
```